# Find component like SelectCheckBoxMenu of PrimeFaces in the Icefaces or JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, icefaces

I am working on kind of old system which uses Icefaces. Now I want to add a component like [SelectCheckBoxMenu of PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/checkboxMenu.xhtml) to select multiple checkbox options in a combo box in the iceFaces datatable header. I searched through out the web but I couldn't find a component like this in Icefaces or JSF. Can we find a component like this in Icefaces or JSF?

I tried to use PrimeFaces together with Icefaces dataTable but even though "SelectCheckBoxMenu" displayed and worked properly, all columns of dataTable deviated and don't display properly. Can we use both Primefaces and iceFaces together?

Comment: did you try BootsFaces? Normally you can use both PF and IceFaces together, but this can cause you certain nuisance when combining different components - so my opinion is DON'T DO IT. But then we have here BootsFaces which are quite new JSF framework and work good with PF and other Frameworks. see http://www.bootsfaces.net

Comment: @JokerTheFourth Thanks for the comment.! No I didn't try BootsFaces but seems like a good alternative. But we can't change from IceFaces to BootsFaces suddenly since this is a quite big project. Thats why I tried to find a multicheck box component in IceFaces. But since this is bit old technology, we are planning to do a technology transform, but it will take some time.